# Separate Cents and dollars values Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm new with oracle queries and I would like to have some help as I'm totally stuck.

I have a Products table which contains the product id, price and product name:
And I would like to separate the price for the products into dollars and cents using select oracle query.

I don't know how to figure that but I tried the TRUNC function but I'm still can't get the cents values.

Can you help me please.

Here is the DB Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
    ProductID int,
    Price varchar(255),
    ProductName varchar(255)
);
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (1,5.17,'Apple');
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (2,6.527,'Orange');
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (3,7.12,'Watermelon');
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (4,3.25,'Pear');
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (5,4.123,'Grape');
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: putting price into a string (varchar) is a fatal design flaw.  Fix your table so that PRICE is properly typed as a NUMBER, with appropriate scale an precision.     And in oracle, when you _do_ properly type a data element as a string, it should be VARCHAR2, not VARCHAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query:**

```
Select productid,trunc(price) As  Dollars, nvl(substr(price - trunc(price),2),0) as Cents, ProductName As Product From Products;
```

**Output:**

| PRODUCTID | DOLLARS | CENTS | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 17 | Apple |
| 2 | 6 | 527 | Orange |
| 3 | 7 | 12 | Watermelon |
| 4 | 3 | 25 | Pear |
| 5 | 4 | 123 | Grape |

Description:

Here I select the ProductId and then I use `trunc` function to remove any decimals (to have only the DOLLARS value) and after that I use `nvl` function to make like a replacement to `null` values (In case there are no cents in number) it will be replaced by `0` and the line: `substr(price - trunc(price),2)`  that will subtract the full price from the DOLLARS value to get the `cents`.

**Note:**
You can solve this problem by different ways and other functions check this article for more informations: [Link](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/from-floor-to-ceiling-and-other-functional-cases)

Comment: This is wrong as the Orange is not 6 dollars and 527 cents.

Comment: Yes I know that I think it is all about how to do that not the main problem he/she facing.

Answer (score 1):

here is what you need.

```
select substr(price, 1, instr(price, '.')-1) dollars, substr(price, instr(price, '.')+1) cents,  round(substr(price, instr(price, '.')),2)* 100 cents_rounded
from products
```

Comment: Added "cents_rounded" col

Comment: You don't need to `ROUND` and can get the exact cents value (including decimal places).

Comment: @MT0 it will then copy your answer which I don't want it to (;

Comment: It would get the same output as my answer but would be using a different method (string functions vs arithmetic functions). There is no plagiarism in getting the same output and showing a different method of achieving it.

Answer (score 1):

`PRICE` as `VARHCAR2`? Why? It **should be** a `NUMBER` as it **is** a numeric value. In that case:

```
SQL> desc products
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 PRODUCTID                                          NUMBER(38)
 PRICE                                              NUMBER
 PRODUCTNAME                                        VARCHAR2(255)

SQL> SELECT productid,
  2         productname,
  3         price,
  4         --
  5         TRUNC (price) dollars,
  6         (price - TRUNC (price)) * 100 cents
  7    FROM products;

 PRODUCTID PRODUCTNAM      PRICE    DOLLARS      CENTS
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Apple            5,17          5         17
         2 Orange          6,527          6       52,7
         3 Watermelon       7,12          7         12
         4 Pear             3,25          3         25
         5 Grape           4,123          4       12,3

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `TRUNC` to get the dollar value and `MOD` (modulo) to get the cents value:

```sql
SELECT ProductID,
       ProductName,
       TRUNC( Price ) AS dollars,
       MOD( Price, 1 ) * 100 AS cents
FROM   Products
```

Which, for your sample data, outputs:

> ```
> PRODUCTID | PRODUCTNAME | DOLLARS | CENTS
> --------: | :---------- | ------: | ----:
>         1 | Apple       |       5 |    17
>         2 | Orange      |       6 |  52.7
>         3 | Watermelon  |       7 |    12
>         4 | Pear        |       3 |    25
>         5 | Grape       |       4 |  12.3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d68db4f48e621a0c11367398e6c8a24b)*

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace FUNCTION METE(p_number VARCHAR, p_parent VARCHAR, p_child VARCHAR) RETURN VARCHAR
IS
v___left VARCHAR2(4000);
v___right VARCHAR2(4000);
v___number VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
SELECT p_number INTO v___number FROM DUAL WHERE p_number LIKE '%.%';
IF v___number IS NOT NULL THEN

select rtrim((select rtrim(p_number,(select substr(p_number,(select instr(p_number,'.')from dual)+1) from dual)) from dual),'.') 
into v___left
from dual;
select substr(p_number,(select instr(p_number,'.')from dual)+1)
INTO v___right
from dual;

RETURN NVL(v___left,'0')||' '||p_parent||' '||NVL(v___right,'0')||' '||p_child;
ELSIF v___number IS NULL THEN
select substr(p_number,(select instr(p_number,'.')from dual)+1) 
INTO v___right
from dual;
RETURN NVL(v___right,'0')||' '||p_parent;
END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
select substr(p_number,(select instr(p_number,'.')from dual)+1) 
INTO v___right
from dual;
RETURN NVL(v___right,'0')||' '||p_parent;
END;
```

[select ProductID, mete(price,'Dollar','Cent') price, productname from Products;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu3QQ.jpg)